# How to get layout_weight programmatically?

Tags: android, layout

I have simple question: How to get layout_weight programmatically? I seen many topics, when some Layoute set layout_weight, but how to get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) with `getLayoutParams()` on a `View` the parent of which is a `LinearLayout`. The `LayoutParams` object has a `weight` field.

Comment: So, I can't set layout_weight for TableRow(

Comment: You can, `TableRow` is-a `LinearLayout` and `TableLayout.LayoutParams` is-a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 4):

this is answer:

```
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)yourView.getLayoutParams()).weight
```

this value will return you weight of yourView and notice that your view should be in a linearlayout and had a weight before